# Syntax coloring a file with a non-standard extension in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm probably missing something very obvious here. I have files with the extension .st that contain (mostly) C++ code. I want the C++ in there to be highlighted when I open it with Visual Studio. I go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->File Extension. I type 'st' in the 'extension' box and select 'Microsoft Visual C++' as the editor (I also tried 'source code editor' but that didn't help). But I still don't get syntax coloring. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried it, exactly as you describe, and it worked OK, although I had to close the .st file and reopen it to see the change.

Comment: Ughh see I knew it was going to be something obvious :) Thanks.